# If a finite Radon measure admits a derivative then it is of the form $u d\mathcal{L}^N$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

**Problem:** suppose that $\mu$ is a finite Radon measure in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ such that there exists a finite Radon measure $\nu$ such that:
$$\int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x_i} d\mu = - \int_{\Omega} \varphi d\nu_i$$
for all $\varphi \in C^1_c(\Omega)$.
Show that there exists a unique $u \in BV(\Omega)$ such that $\mu=u \mathcal{L}^N$.

**Attempt:** uniqueness is clear. In fact if the property above holds for $u_1$ and $u_2$ then we obtain that $D(u_1-u_2)=0$ which implies $u_1=u_2$ in every connected component.
I am stuck proving existence. I tried using Besicovitch's theorem proving that $\{x : \lim\limits_{\rho \to 0}\frac{|\mu|(B(x,\rho))}{\mathcal{L}^N(B(x,\rho))}= +\infty\}=\emptyset$. In fact this is the support of $\mu^{\perp}$ in the equality $\mu=u \mathcal{L}^N+\mu^{\perp}$.

Comment: What does "$d v_i$" mean?

Comment: @PhoemueX You are right, I edit the question.

Comment: I like the following approach:

Consider the currents $\vec{T_i}=\mu \vec{e_i}$ where $\vec{e_i}$ is the i-th vector of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. These are clearly normal currents due to the assumptions and their vector parts generates the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ $\mu$-almost everywhere: moreover $\mu << ||\vec{T_i}||$ for every $i=1,...,n$. As a result you get $\mu << \mathcal{L}^n$ from Corollary $1.12$ in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.06543.pdf.

Comment: What is your definition of $BV$ ?